# Applications of Quantum Teleportation

Tags: quantum-teleportation

Are there any practical or theoretical applications for quantum teleportation?
I have tried looking online but its unclear if there are any others (other than quantum encryption)

Comment: mostly small scale but big is useful as well, any information helps